# Embedding npplugin in firefox XUL Runner Extension

Tags: plugins, firefox-addon, npapi, xulrunner

I have developed an npapi plugin which is working fine standalone. I want to embed that plugin into a XUL runner Firefox Extension. What i am doing in borwserOverlay.xul is this

```
<menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup">
    <menu id="xulschoolffextension-ffext-menu" label="&xulschoolffextension.ffext.label;" insertbefore="devToolsEndSeparator">
      <menupopup>
        <menuitem id="xulschoolffextension-ffext-menu-item"
          label="&xulschoolffextension.ffextplay.label;" oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.play(event);" />       
      </menupopup>
    </menu>
  </menupopup>


    <html:embed id="pluginobj" type="application/xpcom-recorder" width=0 height=0> </html:embed>
```

When i remove the pluginobj html tag i can see the extension option in my browser, but when i add this then the option is not visible. I suppose this is causing error or is included at wrong place. What i am achieving via this is to call Plugin object function from JS event.